# How can I tell if I have GreenHopper installed on Jira?

Tags: jira, greenhopper

I'm using Jira and have been told by the sysadmin that GreenHopper has been installed.

However, I see no evidence that GreenHopper has been installed.

Is there a simple way to determine whether or not GreenHopper has been installed?

Comment: There should be a new top-level tab "Agile". The plugin may have been installed but the license not installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once greenhopper is installed, it needs to be enabled for the project.  In the greenhopper administration section you can choose to enable it for all projects or only selected ones.

I believe the default setting has it only for selected projects, with none selected.

Edit: you can find that setting in the administration section under Greenhopper -> Enabled Projects.

Answer (score 3):

The [video on GreenHopper](http://www.atlassian.com/software/greenhopper/) illustrates some of the feature that you should be able to see.

In particular, you should be able to access the **[Planning Board](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/Using+the+Planning+Board)** on your project, meaning there should be an 'Agile' link's down-arrow in the top navigation bar and a 'Planning Board' from the resulting dropdown menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are a JIRA Admin, simply go to the Adminstration > JIRA Administration > System > Plugin, the look at the "Installed plugin" section whether you have "GreenHopper".

I you are not a JIRA Admin, and you are running the latest version of JIRA and GreenHopper, you will see the "Agile" tab besides the "Dashboard", "Projects", "Issues".